# Javascript function call to c# method to get array of integers for datatables.net column order

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I must profess that i am not very good with Javascript.

I am creating a table using datatables.net
The datatable is populated using a call to a generic handler that will then call the database (in c#) to get values.  This is working. 
What i'd like to do is use the column re-order functionality.  Setting the order is by an array of integers.  I'd like those values to be stored in the database and then assign use it. I haven't thought about the saving columns order part first as i want to get the "get" process working first.

In a normal world, the code to set the column re-order is by coding it into the datatables functionlity like:

```
 <script>
    $(function () {

        var columnOrder = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5];

        $("#<%=DT.ClientID%>").dataTable({
            dom: 'Rlfrtip',
            colReorder: {
                order: columnOrder
            },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bFilter": false, //Hide the search box
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sAjaxSource": "../DataHandler/Data.ashx",
```

So what I'd like to do is to populate the "columnOrder" with values from the database. 
i tried using a webmethod and then getting that value by  $.ajax({ + Post.  This went to my c# code behind method on the default.aspx but returned an empty object.  It also seems to populate the datatable first before going into the webmethod so the timing of the call is not correct as well.

QUESTION: I'm scratching my head if I am over-complicating this.  All i want is the return an array of integers from a c# server-side method to a javascript variable.  Then use this variable to set the order of the column. 
Any suggestion on how i can just get an array of integers from c# into a variable is basically what i'd need to get started.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> All i want is the return an array of integers from a c# server-side method to a javascript variable.

I have a method that return an array of integers, not really an array but it works like one in javascript.

The method is below

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<int> getAdd_Zip(int ZIP_ID)
    {
        try
        {
            BusinessContacts objContacts = new BusinessContacts();
            DataTable dtInf = objContacts.getAdd_Zip(ZIP_ID);
            List<int> lRes = new List<int>();

            if (dtInf.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lRes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dtInf.Rows[0]["COU_ID"]));
                lRes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dtInf.Rows[0]["STE_ID"]));
                lRes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dtInf.Rows[0]["MUN_ID"]));
            }

            return lRes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Note that the method returns a List of integer, I declare a datatable, then I fill that table with another method (this not important), then, I fill the List with 3 values.

So now, I have the next method on javascript

```
function wsGetAdd_Zip(ZIP_ID) {
var AddZips = new Array();
var params = new Object();
params.ZIP_ID = ZIP_ID;
params = JSON.stringify(params);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Contactos.aspx/getAdd_Zip",
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        AddZips = result.d;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});

return AddZips;
}
```

That method returns the array of integers.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. your code makes sense. I tried something similar using your code as a guideline. the error i get now is: "Is not supported for deserialization of an array."

I think i need to go back to the Javascript basics to figure this out. 

on the other hand. Would it be wrong if I get all the values that i need in c# code behind and then use a public variable on that page and call it up from the javascript? I know that would work. i am not sure if that is a best practice or not. 
thanks again.

Comment: Did you use the same code that I gave you? That error ocurred because of JSON (I guess), if so, you have to import json2.js. I cant remmember where did I download but you can search for it in google.